# android:hint не исчезает при наборе

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Создаю приложение прогноза погоды, хочу, чтобы при вводе своего города задний фон исчезал. Подскажите где искать?

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/citynameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/citynameEditText_placeholderText"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Comment: Что значит чтобы задний фон исчезал?

Comment: Фон у чего? Всмысле исчезал? Подробнее опишите

Comment: Например, как задний фон у меня стоит "Москва", но при вводе другого города "Москва" все еще отображается :(

Answer (score 0):

Существует несколько вариантов:

**ВАРИАНТ 1**

Добавить обработчик на поле. Данные вариант более гибкий, т.е. позволит вам не только цвет фона менять но и все что душе угодно делать:

```
myEditText = findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextNameInxml); 

myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Focus Lose", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Get Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Внутри обработчика, програмно меняете цвет (например так, код схемотично написан):

```
editText.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name));
```

**ВАРИАНТ 2**.

Создаете стиль:

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Добавляете стиль `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"/>
```

Оба вариант рабочие. Второй проще, Первый гибче.

**P.S.**
прозрачный фон:

```
#80000000
```

или

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```